# Creating an Drools Web application

Tags: web-applications, drools, guvnor

Now I can create a drools application and I have used to create a drools application which is found in smooks site (A StockTik Example). Now I want to deploy that in a jboss AS . Is it possible. And is there any simple tutorials for the deployment. I am not interested in using guvnor repository

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap that in War file and deploy it to JBoss AS, but without an interface to the outside world, there's not much it can do. So you could write a webapp interface (using GWT or JSF) or instead some REST services (using resteasy) which accept some sort of input, apply the rules and do some sort of output.

On the other hand, there's **drools-camel-server**, which is a war (to deploy to JBoss AS again) which accepts XML input, applies rules and outputs XML.

Answer (score 0):

Learn JBpm 5.4 it comes with Drools ,you can create web application in jbPM of drools 
and when you r done having rough idea on drools, had enough hands on it you can follow this link

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SimpleJBPM54InsideJBossAS711WebAppExample